# How to export dataTable into Excel and Download with onClick event on button in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, datatables, export-to-excel

I am new to Angular 2 and trying to implement export functionality on dataTable.

I want any examples for exporting datatable into excel with angular 2 without using jQuery. Please advise